# Is it safe to export a value from back-end to front-end?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, systemjs

I have a react app which needs to access a database to get a couple of values. The thing is, it is clearly not safe to store the key to API of that database.

Let's say i created a **backend.js** file. In that file i make a call for the database:

`fetch(URL), {headers: API_KEY}
  .then(data => data.json())`

And i got the response data in a variable called answer. if i do `export default answer`, then in app.js `import answer from "./backend.js"`, when i use that data, can the client potentially get the key/ any other data except for the **answer** from the **backend.js** file, or `export default` only exports the variable?

Comment: Regardless of what platform, I think it all depends on what one is allowed do with this API key.
If the server is validating user input and is secure, why not use a login token , for example? (and use https)

Comment: The server should determine what is allowed for a certain client. If a key is unsafe to store, then don't. 
I guess you need to make access to the database indirect, thru different server API function calls.

Comment: How do you plan on injecting API_KEY into the client? Where would that value come from?

Comment: That's the point. I'll not give the API_KEY to the client in any way.
I will `fetch` the information with my API_KEY and than export the variable with that information.

Comment: You already are giving the API_KEY to client, since your fetch has API_KEY in the headers! When you say "I will `fetch` the information with my API_KEY", where is it stored? In your JS (i.e., client side) code, right?

Comment: What you are describing is not a "back-end", at least as i understand it.  You are talking about a client side file called "backend.js". 

I would suggest looking into Node.js, maybe Express.js as well.  There is a lot of information out there.  Then your frontend could make an request to your backend.

Comment: I will check that out, thanks.